# Flutter not running on Android Device

Tags: android, dart, flutter, grinder

I just created a new project using command palletes in vsCode. then i start android simulator and then flutter run. it's running perfectly on ios not on android .

this debug console response

Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: aidl is missing from '/Users/sachin/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/aidl'
>   * Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>   * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>   BUILD FAILED in 1s
>   Gradle build failed: 1
>   Exited (sigterm)

Comment: can you run `flutter doctor` and `flutter upgrade` and then retry ?

Answer (score 0):

Just now I encounter the same problem. It happened because after doing "flutter run" there's still some file that needs to be downloaded, the `build tools`, but didn't get downloaded correctly, because I stopped it in the middle, since I thought the process was stuck.

So, these are the steps that solve the problem:

1. open terminal
2. change directory to `/Users/[USERNAME]/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/`, in your case, type `cd /Users/sachin/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/`
3. remove the folder that causes the error, in your case the `26.0.2 folder`, so in your terminal type `rm -r 26.0.2` to remove it.
4. go back to your code, make sure the android simulator is detected, and re run the project
5. now, wait patiently, it may takes sometime (depends on internet connection), but it's downloading the `build tools`, you can watch this in the finder by typing `open .`
6. make sure that in the `26.0.2 folder` there's `aidl` file added when the process is finished.
7. it should be working, if not, just rebuild/re-run your code one more time. Done!